# Set multiple reference type values to nil at once

Tags: swift, null, reference-type

Suppose that I have an array of `UIView?`s that have a value by default:

```
var firstView: UIView? = UIView()
var secondView: UIView? = UIView()
let views = [firstView, secondView]
```

I want to change every value that's in the array to `nil`. The ideal solution would be iterating through the elements of the array and setting them to `nil`. However, **this does not work:**

```
print(firstView) //Optional(<UIView: [address]; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: [address]>>)

for i in 0 ..< views.count {
    views[i] = nil
}

//firstView is still not nil
print(firstView) //Optional(<UIView: [address]; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: [address]>>)
```

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: This is not a problem with UIView being a reference type. The *only* way (because you cannot safely take the address of an instance variable) to set `firstView` to `nil` is to assign `firstView = nil`. If you need to nil a whole set of views then hold the references *only* in the array, without separate instance variables.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the additional information, I've written an answer that references this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As MartinR said in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444415/set-multiple-reference-type-values-to-nil-at-once?noredirect=1#comment89859726_51444415), it's not possible to directly modify the address of an instance variable. Some possible solutions for this problem:

- [As MartinR points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444415/set-multiple-reference-type-values-to-nil-at-once?noredirect=1#comment89859726_51444415), you can store the views only in that array and nowhere else. That way, when you make every element in your array `nil`, there won't be any references for the views. However, this can easily produce an overly long or hard-to-understand code.
- A usually better solution for `UIView`s is **creating a custom view** and put all elements in it that you'd store in an array otherwise. That way, you can easily make that one view `nil` and all subviews will be `nil` (since they rely on the superview).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `KeyPath`s:

```
class Foo {
    let views = [\Foo.view1, \Foo.view2]

    var view1: UIView? = UIView()
    var view2: UIView? = UIView()

    func freeAll() {
        print(view1 as Any, view2 as Any)

        for keyPath in views {
            self[keyPath: keyPath] = nil
        }

        print(view1 as Any, view2 as Any)
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.freeAll()
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Optional(<UIView: 0x7fc5c4107bb0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000213e760>>) Optional(<UIView: 0x7fc5c41057a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x60000213d780>>)
> nil nil
> ```

In this case, the `views` array doesn't contain references to the objects, but instead it stores `KeyPath`s which you can think of as directions how to find them.  That allows you to access the objects and set them to `nil` if desired.